# how to associate a goal to a specific phase in maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

I know maven's deploy meaning is "send the artifact to the repository" but what I want to do is associate the [tomcat7-maven-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/)'s deploy goal to the deploy phase or another one like install. I'm not able to associate it with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>userpom</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>userweb</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>userweb</name>
    <url>http://www.test.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>userservices</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>userweb</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!--<plugin>-->
                    <!--<artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>-->
                    <!--<version>2.8.2</version>-->
                <!--</plugin>-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                        <server>TomcatServer</server>
                        <path>/usertest</path>
                        <update>true</update>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>tomcat-deploy</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

while the parent pom is the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>userpom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>userservices</module>
        <module>userweb</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>userpom</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

basically, it's not executed and I have to call it manually:

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy
```

within the userweb folder. Any hint?

Comment: Please show your full pom file...

Comment: sure, u r right. I've updated the question with the full pom

Comment: I would recommend to keep the deployment to Tomcat separated from the maven life cycle but if you like you simply move the tomcat-maven-plugin from pluginManagement to `<build><plugins><plugin> ...</plugin></plugins></build>` instead this will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually defining your `tomcat7-maven-plugin` only in `pluginManagement` but do not refer it anywhere outside in the `build.plugins` section.

A slightly altered version of your `pom.xml` showing only the relevant parts could be:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>userpom</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    […]

    <build>
        <finalName>userweb</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!--<plugin>-->
                    <!--<artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>-->
                    <!--<version>2.8.2</version>-->
                <!--</plugin>-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                        <server>TomcatServer</server>
                        <path>/usertest</path>
                        <update>true</update>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>tomcat-deploy</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If all artifacts which inherit the parent pom.xml shall benefit from your pre-configured `tomcat7-maven-plugin` then pull the `pluginManagement` section out of your sub `pom.xml` and put it into the `build` section of your parent `pom.xml`.